# проблема с калькулятором на java

Tags: java

Хотел бы к вам обратиться с проблемой с моим калькулятором на java
Вот сам код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class keken2{
public static void main(String arr[]){
Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
int result = 0;
System.out.println("enter first number:");
int num1 = input1.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter second number:");
int num2 = input2.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter operation(+, -, *, /):");
String oper = input3.next();
if(oper == "+"){
result = num1 + num2;
System.out.println("result is:" + result);  
}else if(oper == "-"){
result = num1 - num2;
System.out.println("result is:" + result);
}else if(oper == "*"){
result = num1 * num2;
System.out.println("result is:" + result);
}else if(oper == "/"){
result = num1 / num2;
System.out.println("result is:" + result);
}else{
System.out.println("You have entered a wrong operator");
}
}

}
```

Но вместо ожидаемого результата, после введения всех данных появляется только "You have entered a wrong operator". Скажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Comment: а зачем три Scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно делаете сравнение. 
Сравнение строк нужно выполнять с помощью метода equals класса String:

```
str1.equals(str2);
```

Подробнее здесь:
https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/equals-java-sravnenie-strok

Comment: спасибо, ваш совет помог

Comment: Тогда отметьте ответ как правильный(нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом)